# How to extract all .rar files inside a folder (gdrive) from google colab?

Tags: python, directory, google-colaboratory

I have a folder consist of many `.rar` files. I need to extract all `.rar` files inside that folder. I've mounted my gdrive account to the colab. What I've done is:

```
data_path = "content/gdrive/My Drive/folder"
for file in os.scandir(data_path):
    !unrar x file.path "/content/drive/path/output_folder/"
```

but I got error:

```
Cannot open file.path
No such file or directory
No files to extract
```

I think `file.path` will work since when I used:

```
for file in os.scandir(data_path):
    print(file.path)
```

It prints all file paths in that folder

How to accomplish it efficiently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For using variable in !unrar, you need to use this code

```
file_path = '/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/123.rar'
!unrar x '$file_path'
```

So, in your situation you will have next code:

```
data_path = "/content/gdrive/My Drive/folder"
for file in os.scandir(data_path):
    !unrar x '$file.path' "/content/drive/path/output_folder/"
```

Comment: is it possible to set the output directory as a relative path? like so 
`data_path = Path("./Data/")` 
`for file in os.scandir(data_path):    !unrar x '$file.path' data_path`